# Google Map API, search box

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have integrated a Google Map on my page and add a search box to it with the following code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

// Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});                 

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17); 
    }
});
```

Currently this give me a search box with autocompletion list, which is good. But I have to click on a item of this list to go to the location. If I just type something in the input an hit enter, nothing happened..
Any help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

to

```
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```